# sql restricted count query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not certain how to structure a SQL query to return the number of rows where a column equals certain values.

For instance,

In table `myTable`, how can I return the count of all the rows where `myColumn = "xyz"` and where `myColumn = "abc"`? Is this possible with a single query?

To clarify, say there are 10 rows where `myColumn = "xyx"` and 7 rows where `myColumn = "abc"`, the query would return something like:

```
firstCountResult: 10
secondCountResult: 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about?:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*),
    myColumn
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn IN ('xyz', 'abc')
GROUP BY myColumn
```

This approach also works with other aggregate functions like MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM... You get the aggregate result per the grouped column's value versus across all rows.

```
--min myDate per myColumn value
SELECT
    MIN(myDate),
    myColumn
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn IN ('xyz', 'abc')
GROUP BY myColumn

--sum of myNumericCol per myColumn value
SELECT
    SUM(myNumericCol),
    myColumn
FROM myTable
WHERE myColumn IN ('xyz', 'abc')
GROUP BY myColumn
```

Comment: Never do  count(*), count(1) or count(column in a non null used index) is better.

Comment: Hmmm. The difference between count(*) and count(1) may not be what you expect: [Ask Tom discussion](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789), [oracledba.co.uk](http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/count_speed.htm). I suppose a non-null indexed column might make sense, but I didn't have one available.

Comment: @stjohnroe, count(*) is identical to count(1).

Comment: Actually, after a read around, it seems that I may be wrong, interesting thread on the masters site http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789

Answer (score 2):

You want to group the count by mycolumn so you do this

```
select 
         myColumn, count(*)
from  
         myTable 
where 
         myColumn in ('xyz','abc')
group by 
         myColumn
```